# Is there a way to use the Zend Service Manager as an isolated component instead of wrapped in a ZF2 application

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a personal project that uses a different application structure than `Zend Framework 2` however we are using the framework as a `vendor`.

I'd like to use the `Zend Service Manager` still as a broker for objects. Is there a way to just **instantiate the Zend Service Manager** without `ZF2` as an object loading factory?

Answer (score 2):

The `Zend\ServiceManager` can be leveraged effectively with or without `Zend\ModuleManager` and `Zend\Mvc`, and the application structure typically associated with them.  However, the service manager will still require an instance of `Zend\ServiceManager\Config` or an implementation of `ConfigInterface`, which works to define factories, services, aliases, etc.

```
<?php
$configArray = [
    'invokables' => [
        /* invokables */
    ],
    'factories' => [
        /* factories */
    ],
];
$config = new \Zend\ServiceManager\Config($configArray);
$serviceManager = new \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager($config);
```

Furthermore, instead of loading the entire framework, the `zendframework/zend-servicemanager` package can be loaded via Composer, or downloaded directly at https://github.com/zendframework/zend-servicemanager.